# How to use the new Tweeter timeline embedding widget?

Tags: javascript, web-services, twitter, embed

I can't get the new Twitter timeline embedding feature to work.

Apparently anybody can embed anybody's Twitter timeline now, providing said timeline is not "protected", which is the default setting anyway.

Logged on, in the "Settings and privacy" menu entry, there is a "Widgets" tab that gets you to [a page](https://publish.twitter.com/#) that says "You currently have no widgets" with a "Create new" button next to it ; Clicking said button taks you to a page where you enter the name of the user whose timeline you want to embed.

Then, a message saying "That’s **all we need**, unless you’d like to set customization options ; By embedding Twitter content in your website or app, you are agreeing to the Developer Agreement and Developer Policy." end of quote, emphasis mine ; and here is the code snippet :

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Now at this stage, if you go back to you "widgets" settings tab, it still says "You currently have no widgets." so, hum :( And here is what happens when I copy and paste the code snippet :

https://jsfiddle.net/wr6y60xo/

Only text links are displayed, the timeline is not rendered. The external JS script is pulled in OK though, I checked.

Am I missing something here? I tried pasting it alone in an empty basic HTML page, tried with different browsers, disabled any JS filtering gizmo, no luck, what is going on?

Comment: Nobody? :( What's puzzling me is that I followed the exact procedure, and every comment on the web is about the previous id-based system..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, it is a security problem, most notably Firefox (53.0 64-bit Linux) blocks the rendering of the widget. To unblock it, click on the shield icon next to the URL/Location bar, and click on the "disable" button.